# Time between a time interval in vbscript

Tags: time, vbscript, intervals

I am trying to condition a time read as a string lies between a specified time interval using VBScript. Following is the script:

```vb
dim splitString, currentTime
splitString = Split("12 59 00")
currentTime = TimeSerial(splitString(0),splitString(1), splitString(2))
If ((DateAdd("n",-1,time())) <= currentTime < DateAdd("n", 1,time())) Then 
    Wscript.Echo currentTime
End If
```

This does not seem to work. Getting an echo even if the current time is outside the time interval.

Comment: Pretty sure this would have been asked before in one form or another.

Answer (score 2):

In [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html) you can check 'is in an interval' using the short

```
if x <= y < z:
    ...
```

but in VBScript you need the longer

```
If x <= y And y < z Then
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate both conditions independently.

```
dim splitString, currentTime
splitString = Split("3 39 00")
currentTime = TimeSerial(splitString(0),splitString(1), splitString(2))
If (DateAdd("n",-1,time()) <= currentTime) And (currentTime < DateAdd("n", 1,time())) Then 
    Wscript.Echo currentTime
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `DateDiff`. Modified the IF statement to:

```vb
If (DateDiff("n",DateAdd("n",-1,time()),currentTime) = 1 AND  DateDiff("n",currentTime,DateAdd("n",1,time())) = 1) Then 
    Wscript.Echo currentTime
End If
```

Worked as expected.